# Regex / grep to find filesystem path of X depth

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, grep

I need a regex/grep/sed/whatever expression that will match

```
"F:\vol2\home\USERNAME" /grant ...
```

and not match on anything like these

```
"F:\vol2\home\USERNAME\subfolder" /grant ...
"F:\vol2\subfolder\subfoler2" /grant ...
"F:\vol2\home" /grant
```

Obviously, 'USERNAME' is a variable and needs to be treated as such. I was thinking something like 'home\\[A-Za-z]*[^\\]' but that's obviously not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/home\\[^\\]+\"/{print $1}'
```

seems to work.

In perl, this works too:

```
while (<>) {
  print if (/\"F:\\vol2\\home\\[^\\]+\"/);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '\\' -v user=USERNAME 'NF==4 && $3=="home" && $4 ~ "^"user'
```

splitting on a backslash, there must be 4 fields, the third is "home" and the fourth begins with the *user* variable

Answer (score 0):

grep '\vol2\home\'${USERNAME}'"' x2

Answer (score 0):

If your paths are always the first field,

```
awk '$1~/home\\[^\\]+\"/{print $1}'
```

Or you can split the first field on `\` and check number of tokens to be 4

```
$ ruby -ane 'puts $F[0] if $F[0].split("\\").size==4 && /home/' file
"F:\vol2\home\USERNAME"
```